# Con asp.net core mvc y full .NET Framework 4.7 hosting

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, hosting

Si desarrollo una web con `ASP.NET Core` y el `full .NET Framework 4.7`, si quiero desplegarla, el hosting debe soportar `net core` y el `.NET Framework 4.7` o solamente el `.NET Framework`?

Comment: Hola. Por favor asegúrate que tu pregunta cumple con esta guía __[ask]__.

Comment: Pregunta clara y directa al grano. Lo bueno si breve dos veces bueno. Así está bien la pregunta, bienvenido al sitio user tres cuatro seis uno cuatro dos nueve.

Comment: ¿Te fue útil la respuesta mostrada?

Answer (score 2):

Para correr net core hay un framework especifico que toca instalar en el equipo en donde corra ya sea windows o linux, asi mismo para correr framework 4.7 o cualquiera de sus versiones anteriores, implica instalar en el equipo windows, las librerias que lo soportan.

Link de .net core https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core

Link de framework 4.7 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55170

La unica ventaja que hay realmente es que es posible reutilizar algo de codigo, mas aun si se hacen librerias portables.